# How do I make the ul responsive with boostrap5 inside the div?

Tags: html

Hello I'm trying to make my code responsive I'm making a solitaire game, and I need to make it responsive, this is my codefor the HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="tablero" class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row">
        <ul class="contenedorColumnas list-group  list-group-horizontal">
            <li class="contenedorCartas1 list-group-item">
                <ul id="columna1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="contenedorCartas2 list-group-item">
                <ul id="columna2" class="columDisplay list-group  list-group-horizontal" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="contenedorCartas3 list-group-item">
                <ul id="columna3" class="columDisplay list-group  list-group-horizontal" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="contenedorCartas4 list-group-item">
                <ul id="columna4" class="columDisplay list-group   list-group-horizontal" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="contenedorCartas5 list-group-item">
                <ul id="columna5" class="columDisplay list-group  list-group-horizontal" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="contenedorCartas6 list-group-item">
                <ul id="columna6" class="columDisplay list-group" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="contenedorCartas7 list-group-item">
                <ul id="columna7" class="columDisplay list-group  list-group-horizontal" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>


        <div id="mazos" class="col-sm">
            <div id="mazo_Entrada"></div>
            <div id="almacen"></div>
            <div id="almacen2"></div>
            <div id="almacen3"></div>
            <div id="almacen4"></div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
<script src="js/solitario.js"></script>
```

And for some reasson when I open the html nothing is responsive, and even worts everything looks messsy

Comment: What's currently in your CSS file?

Also, this website has good examples of how to make your page responsive [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)

Comment: Can you share your Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Did you import bootstrap css into your html?

try to add this in your header

```
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

Comment: Yes I did, but nothing change when I make the web smaller things keep in the same possition, plus when I added all the links All went messy, and everything move so I've been changing stuff manually in the css.